# Flink :Write retract stream to kafka sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Can anyone share working example to write retract stream to kafka sink?

I tried as below which is not working.

```
DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, User>> resultStream =
            tEnv.toRetractStream(result, User.class);

resultStream.addsink(new FlinkKafkaProducer(OutputTopic, new ObjSerializationSchema(OutputTopic),
            props, FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the simplest solution would be to do smth like:

```
resultStream.map(elem -> elem.f1)
```

This will allow You to write the `User` objects to Kafka.

But this isn't really that simple from business point of view or at least it depends on the use-case. Kafka is an append-only log and retract stream represents ADD, UPDATE and DELETE operations. So, while the solution above will allow You to write the data to Kafka, the results in Kafka may not correctly represent the actual computation results, because they won't represent update and delete operations.

To be able to write actual correct computation results to Kafka You may try to do one of the following things:

- If You know that Your use-case will never cause any DELETE or UPDATE operations then You can safely use the solution above.
- If the duplicates may be only produced in some regular intervals (for example record may only be updated/deleted after 1 hr after they are produced), you may want to use  windows to aggregate all updates and write one final result to Kafka.
- Finally, You can extend `User` class to add a field which marks whether this record is a retract operation and keep that information when writing data to Kafka topic. This means that You would have to handle all possible UPDATE or DELETE operations downstream (in the consumer of this data).

Comment: In my use case there will be UPDATED events every few mins.Is there a way to filter the events that are marked as DELETE and just write USER object to a kafka topic.

Comment: If You know that the UPDATE can only occur only up to few minutes after original value is emitted then You may try to use windows to aggregate all changes and emit the final result to Kafka.  Hard to say without knowledge of exact usecase :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use the upsert-kafka connector, as a table sink. This is designed to consume a retract stream and write it to kafka.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/upsert-kafka.html